# Get Redux Form Values For Unknown Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, redux-form

I have a component that contains related fields for composition in different forms. Sometimes it belongs to a `FieldArray`. The value of one fields must affect the presentation of another field.

Is there a clean way to access field values in this scenario?

```
const MyReusableFields = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Field
        component={TextField}
        name="fieldA"
      />
      {fieldA === 'something' && // How can he get fieldA's value here?
        <Field
          component={TextField}
          name="fieldB"
        />
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

I don't think I can use `formValueSelector` or `getFormValues` because I don't know the name of the form. Even if I knew the name of the form, I don't know the exact field name because under `FieldArray` it will have an unknowable prefix.

I'm imagining some ugly code searching through state, but I would prefer to use a pattern supported by the framework if it exists.

Comment: But what property are you getting from `fieldA`? You can't just use the component because it's truthy, are you using the form's value?

Comment: That's what I want is the form's value for fieldA. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have roughly answered your question here https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3103#issuecomment-312556081

If you are creating a UI widget for which there are a small number of inter-related fields Fields is perhaps what you want.

It is worth noting, that you can inject the form name from this.context._reduxForm.form - you can make a withFormName HOC to wrap connect and use ownProps.form inside connect to select the values you're looking for.

After this, it becomes architectural questions for you...

For example you seem to state that you don't know the field names because you don't know the context in which the Fields will be. But fieldNames are absolute unless you're using Form sections. For example a Field with name "hello" inside a field array will store it's value under store.form.formName.hello - not under the array prefixed value - unless you pass those prefixes to the component and manually do the prefixing (that's why fields.map returns field names).

The point is that you generally must know the names up front because you're the one specifying them to the Field/Fields components. If you are using FormSections, all three components have a name prop that will return the name taking into account the FormSection context.

For these reasons I cannot really see why you cannot use form value selectors or Fields to create conditional form value filling. Indeed, these really are the only standard ways that you can know the values for conditional rendering of fields.

Note if you use Fields you won't get proper registering/deregistering in the way you do with conditional field rendering but this may or may not matter to you.

Comment: I have solved it using `Fields`. You cannot know the name of the field (what you need to pass into `formValueSelector`) if it's inside a `FieldArray` because those field names get prefixed like `thing[n].fieldA`, where `n` is the index position in the array.

Comment: I would only add that `Fields` is only adequate if the fields that depend upon one another are rendered next to each other. It will not work if they positioned apart in the form.

Comment: Great! Right but thing[0].fieldA is the fully qualified name, and Field can only have that fully qualified name if you've told it that's what it's fully qualified name is? Like you know it's name at some point?

Comment: No. Take the example code in my question. It will be rendered `n` times, and I don't know what `n` is inside my component unless I pass it down the whole tree from `fields.map((thingName, index) => {...`

Comment: Further `MyReusableFields` does not know whether it is being rendered in a `FieldArray` or singly.

Comment: That's where I don't follow. If you give fieldB name fieldB then you can select it's value using formValueSelecter with "fieldB". It won't matter where it is or what it's inside (excepting the FormSection case). If it's inside a field array and you give it name fieldB it's name is fieldB not thing[0].fieldB - that's not how FieldArray works.

Comment: When I tried `formValueSelector` it was expecting the fully qualified path to the form value. Simply using the last node (the field name out of context) was not working. It does not seem to know the component I'm connecting is in the nth item of the array or inside a section. I'll try again, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: That is correct, you must pass it the fully qualified name. But you must also pass the fully qualified name to the Field component. In your example you're passing "fieldA". Which is not the fully qualified name. If you were passing the fully qualified name, you would then know the fully qualified name, and you could access this in ownProps with formValueSelector

Comment: No, you pass the name to the field component, not the fully qualified name, which would be impossible. So per mu OP example, `<Field component={TextField} name="fieldA" />` not `<Field component={TextField} name="mySection.myArray[7].fieldA" />`.

Comment: Sorry I incorrectly edited my comment before while someone was distracting me, the original was correct: 
 
Voila. You should pass `myArray[7].fieldA`. `FieldSection` _does_ auto-prefix the input.name passed to TextField, while `FieldArray` auto prefixing _does not_ happen. This is the whole point of the iteration methods in FieldArray see the example in redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/FieldArray.md. If you pass "fieldA" then `input.name` will be `mySection.fieldA`.

Comment: I found where the disconnect is. My example so far have been imprecise. You are correct, arrays don't auto-prefix. My hierarchy within the array item is actually like `<FormSection name={[backtick]${member}.mySection[backtick]} /><Field name="fieldA" />`. So when I connect the component holding fieldA, I do not have a handle on the full field name. I can correct this by eliminating the section and passing the full prefix down to the component. It's super ugly, especially for deeply nested forms, but it would work.

Comment: No one said choosing a good architecture for ReduxForm was easy - but a good one is certainly required for complex situations like these! As soon as you need the types of data being passed by the connected ReduxForm components to the components you pass to them outside of the ReduxForm component - things get interesting. Erik did also mention you can just use Field itself as your data fetcher - no rule it has to render a field. Seems a hack but they are just connectors at the end of the day..

Comment: How reluctant should I be to using `this.context._reduxForm.form` as you suggested? In javascript land underscore is a warning that it's not part of the public API and this liable to be broken, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use formValueSelector form redux form. Example (In this example the template fields only show if template checkbox is checked):

```
import { reduxForm, Field, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

let UnitReduxForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, templateCheckboxActive } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <Field
          id="templateChecked"
          name="templateChecked"
          label="Unidad basada en plantilla"
          component={renderCheckboxField}
          type="checkbox"
        />
        {templateCheckboxActive && (
          <Field
            id="template"
            name="template"
            label="Plantilla"
            items={[
              { value: "cocina", label: "Plantilla Cocina" },
              { value: "bano", label: "Plantilla Baño" },
              { value: "sala", label: "Plantilla Sala" },
              { value: "comedor", label: "Plantilla Comedor" }
            ]}
            component={renderSelectField}
          />
        )}
    </form>
  )
}

//redux form
UnitReduxForm = reduxForm({ form: "unit" })(UnitReduxForm);
//selector
const selector = formValueSelector("unit");
UnitReduxForm = connect(state => {
  const templateCheckboxActive = selector(state, "templateChecked");
  return { templateCheckboxActive };
})(UnitReduxForm);

export default UnitReduxForm;
```

More info in: [https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/][1]